# How to reduce lag while streaming live video?

Tags: android, video-streaming, video-encoding, live-streaming

I am currently working on an android application in which i have to stream the mobile camera footage live to a public URL. I have managed to convert the .MP4 format to .FLV format so that the video stream can be viewed in a browser using a flash plugin. However, the lag in the stream is about 10-15 seconds. Can anyone suggest dome compression techniques or other tricks and tweaks so that i can reduce the lag time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use JW player for faster playback. Also reduce buffering by using suitable flashvar.
refer http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/13/embedding-flash.

If you are streaming over WiFi you may face more delay.